# Error while executing php script to sql database

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying the following:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID, `LAST NAME` AS lm, `FIRST NAME` AS fm FROM `OLD`";
$sql .= " UNION ALL SELECT ID, `Last Name` AS lm, `First Name` AS fm, FROM `NEW`) ";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$params = array();
$sth->execute($params);
$ids = $lm = $fm = $dp = $ex = $bp = $em = array();
$counter = 0;
while ($row = $sth->fetch()) {

    $ids[] = $row['ID'];
    $lm[] = $row['lm'];
    $fm[] = $row['fm'];

    $counter++;
}

for($j=0;$j < $counter;$j++) {
    $new = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, lastname, firstname)";
    $new.= " VALUES( '".$ids[$j]."', '".$lm[$j]."', '".$fm[$j]."')";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $new);
    if( !$stmt ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    } 
}
?>
```

This shows the following error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'. ) )

Inside my for loop, if i try to echo $lm[$j] and $fm[$j] variables i get my results normally, but for some reason query is not executing.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you juse use `INSERT INTO MYTABLE (...) SELECT * FROM ...` instead of a loop?

Comment: SQL-Server doesn't use backticks to quote names, it uses square brackets.

Comment: So it should be `[LAST NAME]`

Comment: you know PHP supports multi-line strings, right?

Comment: As you can see i collect data from access database and then insert it into sql server database. As i wrote above, i get the results correctly from access database file. Backticks are used in access file query not for sql server query.

Comment: @Spiris "As you can see..": No we cannot see that. The question is tagged with sql server and the error message is from sql server. Anyway, you should alias your subquery: `FROM NEW) as x`.